# object is set but property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have created a class as below:

```
export class User{
    private _name:string

    User(){}

    get name():string{
        return this._name
    }

    set name(val:string){
        this._name = val
    }

}
```

now in my code at login i am fetching data from server side and assigning it to a variable as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './modal/user.modal';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoreService {
  user:User

  constructor() { }
}
```

login.ts

```
 this.core.user = await this.dataSvc.fetchCustomer(resp.user.uid)
      console.log("user is:", Object.keys(this.core.user))
      console.log("user is:", Object.values(this.core.user))

      console.log("user is:", this.core.user)
      console.log("user name is:", this.core.user.name)
```

Below is the response and the last line of printing name undefined is something i am not able to figure out

```
user is: 
Array(5) [ "_email", "_joinDate", "_name", "_phone", "_uid" ]
main.js:469:17
user is: 
Array(5) [ "vik.ceo@gmail.com", 1658372252068, "Vivek Kumar", "6508670697", "AoaFKbEzrYcjZUE283rI4dpSYh92" ]
main.js:470:17
user is: 
Object { _email: "vik.ceo@gmail.com", _joinDate: 1658372252068, _name: "Vivek Kumar", _phone: "6508670697", _uid: "AoaFKbEzrYcjZUE283rI4dpSYh92" }
main.js:471:17
user name is: undefined
```

Comment: `fetchCustomer()` is asynchronous, but you're trying to log the properties immediately.

Comment: @phuzi surely, that's because `user.name` should using the getter to retrieve the property?

Comment: @user1599011 `fecthCustomer` is `await`ed so no, the code waits for the response before continuing.

Comment: correct its using getter and argument on fetchCustomer being async is not valid either. the print of this.core.user is printing data just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no getter and setter, cause you haven't created an instance of `User` class. You've just assigned value returned from `fetchCustomer` to user property in the service.

So your code should be like:

```
export class User{
    private _name:string

    constructor(name: string) {
       this._name = name;
    }


    get name():string{
        return this._name
    }

    set name(val:string){
        this._name = val
    }
}

const user = await this.dataSvc.fetchCustomer(resp.user.uid);
this.core.user = new User(user.name); // as mentioned in the comments your response contains `_name` property instead of `name`
```

Comment: but this.core.user is printing the assigned values just fine. just the specific  user.name is undefined. i am sure something is wrong but not very convinced that i have to specifically assign each property

Comment: it prints properties from response object - it's obvious, as they start with `_`. For assigning multiple properties you can change constructor to `constructor(src) { 
 Object.assign(this, src) }`